# Eye frame rate dropping when tired

Tags: vision, fatigue

I have always wondered what causes one's frame rate to drop in their eyes when tired. Could anyone explain this?

I am talking about the effect when your vision goes almost stuttery

Comment: Not off topic. This was not intended to be a personal medical issue, it is a general question about the human body. I have reworded it for clarity. Please reopen.

Comment: Removing personal details improved the question, but I don't think your video analogy is sufficient to attract reopen votes. This site has the additional requirement that questions must show some degree of prior research, so even if it gets reopened it will probably be closed again due to that. Does this phenomenon have a name? Has anyone written papers on the subject? Those would be things you might want to look into and add to your question.

Comment: I have done prior research but there doesn't appear to be any. That's actually why I'm asking here :) It's a topic for which it is quite hard to Google (lexicon is unclear) so I would be more than satisfied if a comment pointed me in a helpful direction in lieu of any actual answer.